# In React Router how can I route to 2 similar urls with a different param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For example I have a `<Song />` route which plays a song, and I want another route `<SongInfo />` to show info on the song and another `<SongComments />` to show the comments.

```
<Route path="songs" component={Songs} />
<Route path="song/:id/:name" component={Song} />
<Route path="songs/:id/:name/:info" component={SongInfo} />
<Route path="songs/:id/:name/:comments" component={SongComments} />
```

I want the url structure to look like the following:

```
/songs/123/cool_song/
/songs/123/cool_song/info
/songs/123/cool_song/comments
```

How do I achieve this? As currently the last 2 routes are the same and go to the same Component.

I am using `react-router: 1.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info` and `comments` are static words or they are variables? I ask because in routes you use them as variables but in example you use them as static words.
If they never change, then your routes should look like :

```
<Route path="songs" component={Songs} />
<Route path="song/:id/:name" component={Song} />
<Route path="songs/:id/:name/info" component={SongInfo} />
<Route path="songs/:id/:name/comments" component={SongComments} />
```

(I removed colon before info and comments). Now If you have url `/songs/123/cool_song/info` it will run `SongInfo` component. If you have url `/songs/123/cool_song/comments` it will run `SongComments`.

But if info and comments are variables which will be replaced by some string then the problem is with the last two routers that they are identical. Even if human have to decide e.g. `/songs/123/cool_song/great-song`, `great-song` is comment or info? You have to make them different. For example:

```
<Route path="songs" component={Songs} />
<Route path="song/:id/:name" component={Song} />
<Route path="songs/:id/:name/i/:info" component={SongInfo} />
<Route path="songs/:id/:name/c/:comments" component={SongComments} />
```

and your urls will look:

```
/songs/123/cool_song/i/great-song // info
/songs/123/cool_song/c/great-song // comment
```

Comment: The first solution worked well for me, `path='songs/:id/:name/info'` and  `path='songs/:id/:name/comments'` for the comments and info version of the song route. Thanks